# "Such a good day!" Is this gramatically correct? Is it a complete sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. "Such a good day!"

> 2. "Such a bad question!"

Are these gramatically correct?

What about this:

> 3. " Such a warm feeling reading this post! "

I wonder whether they are complete sentences just like:

> 4. "What a great shot!"

> 5. "What a ridiculous example!"

Comment: *Such nonsense!*     Something is utter nonsense.  It's elliptical and contextual.

Comment: I would have replied to this this with just *Yes.* but it was too short . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not complete sentences, because they don't have a subject and a verb.  Because they are not complete sentences, asking whether they're "grammatically correct" is sort of a question without an answer.  They don't contain any glaring errors and are correct *as phrases*.  (Technically, something like "What a great shot!" is an [exclamation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/emphasising-and-downtoning/exclamations), which is not quite a complete sentence either.)

If we look at them as stand-alone utterances, the question is whether they are understandable and idiomatic.  To this northeastern US English speaker, yes, they are understandable and at least reasonably idiomatic.  They are an example of [conversational deletion](https://learnenglishwithdemi.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/conversational-deletion/) of "**That is** such a bad idea/great question/etc.)" just like "What a great idea!" can be considered short for "What a great idea **that is**!"

"Such a warm feeling reading this post!" could be read as conversational deletion for "**I have** such a warm feeling reading this post!" but it feels much less idiomatic, because the deleted part in exclamations is almost always "This/that/those is/was/are/were".